# Zoom In dyGraphs in R and save image as png

Tags: r, zooming, dygraphs

I want to zoom in the dygraphs and save the image as png. I have plot the graph using dygraph library and saved it as png but it is not zoomed in version.

```
library("webshot")
library("htmlwidgets")
lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5, 
              highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2,
              hideOnMouseOut = FALSE)

saveWidget(ab, "/path/", selfcontained = TRUE, libdir = NULL)

basePng <- paste("images",paste(file,".png"), sep='/')
webshot::webshot("/path/",file=basePng)
```

[image]

But I want plot as below(zoomed in):

[image]

I want to plot zoomed in dygraph for more than 1000 files. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: why not a screenshot?

Comment: @MLavoie Screenshot would work, i used webshot to save the screenshot as png. Problem, here is I am not able to zoom in the plot in the code before saving it as a screenshot.

Comment: No I mean a manual screenshot? For instance on a mac, it is I think cmd + shift + 4.

Comment: @MLavoie, I have some 4000 plots, it's not feasible to save all of them manually.

Comment: what about the zoom? You don't say if this going to be the same for the 4000 plots. `webshot`has zoom option.

Comment: I want to zoom in before taking the screenshot. Because If I zoom in while taking the webshot then I will not get the day and month on the x-axis(as desired output), will get month year instead. That's the reason I am looking to zoom before taking screenshot.

Comment: It would be easier to change the label of the x-axis to `day-month`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this answer could help anyone,

I use `dyRangeSelector()` to "zoom" on the graph, then `webshot`to save it.

```
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dygraphs)

# webshot::install_phantomjs()

lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
        dyRangeSelector( dateWindow = c("1974-03-1","1974-06-10")) %>%
        dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5, 
              highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2,
              hideOnMouseOut = FALSE)

saveWidget(ab,file ="ab.html", selfcontained = TRUE, libdir = NULL)

webshot(url = "ab.html",file="ab.png")
```